# Cant update children of <p:outputPanel>

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, mojarra

I cannot get the children under the p:outputPanel called 'emailDetail' to update. If instead I set to update the 'output' that component updates just fine. Am I doing anything obviously wrong or can I not update this way?

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/xhtml/templates/basictemplate.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <ui:param name="header" value="small-header"/>

    <ui:define name="content">

        <div style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>

        <h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable id="myDataList" value="#{emailView.inboxEmailHeaders}" var="emailHeader" 
                         selectionMode="single" selection="#{emailView.selectedEmailHeader}"
                         rowKey="#{emailHeader.emailId}" scrollable="true" scrollRows="" scrollHeight="200">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                        listener="#{emailView.onRowSelect}"
                        update=":emailDetail" />

                <f:facet name="header">Inbox</f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Id" width="20%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{emailHeader.emailId}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{emailHeader.sender}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{emailHeader.subject}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>

        <h:outputText id="outside" value="#{emailView.selectedEmailHeader.subject}"/> 

        <p:outputPanel id="emailDetail" style="text-align:center;">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{not empty emailView.selectedEmailHeader}" columnClasses="label,value">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="sit"/> 
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="Id:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{emailView.selectedEmailHeader.emailId}" />
                <h:outputText value="Recieved" />
                <h:outputText value="#{emailView.selectedEmailHeader.recieved.toString}" />
                <h:outputText value="Subject" />
                <h:outputText value="#{emailView.selectedEmailHeader.subject}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Thanks for your help.

Ectomorph.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I replaced the `<p:ajax>` tag with an `<f:ajax>` and `update` to `render`, so the tag now looks like this...

```
<f:ajax
    event="rowSelect"
    listener="#{emailView.onRowSelect}"
    render=":emailDetail" />
```

Issues with `<p:ajax>` ?? Hope this helps other folks.

Cheers.
Ecto.

Comment: Well, it solved my problem BalusC, but you are aright, technically it is a workaround.